# Trying to call function i-times in OCaml with a for cycle

Tags: ocaml

I have been trying to create a cycle to call an `changing` function `i`-times , but for some reason the cycle itself always spits out an error. I have also tried an recursive function to call itself but didn't work either.

Is it even possible to make it work with for`s.

`r` is a list of lists.

`a` and `b` are two immutable variables.

`(List.nth (r) (i))` gives an list.

```
let rec changing (lista: 'a zlista) (a:int) (b:int) = 
  match lista with    
  | Vazio          -> failwith "NO"
  | Nodo (n, l, r) -> 
    if a <= n && n <= b then n
    else if a < n && b < n then changing l a b 
    else  changing r a b


let rec call_changing (a: int) (b: int) =
  for i=0 to ort do
    changing (List.nth (r) (i)) (a) (b)
  done;;
```

Comment: "spits out an error" - what's the error?

Comment: sometimes type unit was expected and sometimes just random errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing returns an int, in order to call it in a for loop you have to `ignore` the result of the function :

```ml
for i = 0 to ort do
   let _ = changing .... in ()
done

(* Or *)

for i = 0 to ort do
   ignore (changing ....)
done
```

**EDIT :**

If you want to print the result you can do :

```ml
for i = 0 to ort do
   Printf.printf "Result for %d iteration : %d\n" i (changing ....)
done
```

See [the Printf documentation](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Printf.html) for more information

Comment: i need a way to output the int in the changing functions i-times i cant ignore the output

Comment: I updated my answer to print the result @Bigodes2096

Answer (score 0):

To perhaps generalize on Butanium's answer, OCaml is not a pure functional programming language. It does contain imperative features. Imperative features are all about side-effects. Functions which exist for the purpose of their side-effects on the system (like `Printf.printf`) by convention return `()` (the literal for the `unit` type).

A for loop is an imperative feature. As such, it expects that any expression (or *expessions* chained with `;`) contained within will return `unit`. If they do not, you will receive warnings.

The for loop expression itself (`for ... = ... to ... do ... done`) returns `unit` so the warning can clue you in that any code in the loop which does not have side-effects is inconsequential, and while your code will compile and run, it may not do what you expect.

As a side note, I believe you may be a little overzealous with the parentheses, likely making your code harder to read.

> ```
> let rec call_changing (a: int) (b: int) =
> for i=0 to ort do
> changing (List.nth (r) (i)) (a) (b)
> done;;
> ```

Properly indented and with extraneous parens removed:

```
let rec call_changing (a: int) (b: int) =
  for i=0 to ort do
    changing (List.nth r i) a b
  done;;
```